# To find lowest values using conditional formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

i want to color the lowest values among the list using conditional formula. is it possible if the values are in the same row but in different columns? if yes highlight the cell in which the lowest value is.

here is a sample sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oHG6XV4ztnArIzmjq2Ja05LHuv6u7eY6rRpDgSjMBi4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add conditional formatting to the cells you want to:

Go to `format => conditional formatting` and then set to `color scale` and in the `range`, select the cells you want to verify

[image]

Added to your sheet another sheet with what I explain here

To just highlight the highest, then go for `single color => custom formula => =A:A=MIN($A1:$H7)`

[image]